# Cannot generate superadmin.p12 in ejbca

Tags: installation, ant, flask-superadmin

I install EJBCA but i can not access the https://localhost:8443/ejbca/adminweb/. Environment: Windows 10 jboss-as-7.1.1.Final apache-ant-1.8.2 ejbca_ce_6_3_1_1. I try to generate superadmin.p12 as the install guide by "ant install" command but unsuccessful. The error code showon "BUILD FAILED
C:\PKI\ejbca_ce_6_3_1_1\build.xml:64: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\PKI\ejbca_ce_6_3_1_1\build.xml:70: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\PKI\ejbca_ce_6_3_1_1\bin\cli.xml:94: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\PKI\ejbca_ce_6_3_1_1\bin\cli.xml:112: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\PKI\ejbca_ce_6_3_1_1\bin\cli.xml:186: Java returned: 1".

Attempted restarting the JBOSS service, but the issue persists. Thank you for any assistance or guidance you can provide! Need to anybody help me resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

The version you are trying to use is like 8 years old. I think the best advice is to try the latest release from project [homepage](https://www.ejbca.org/). You can also use it easily as a container from [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/keyfactor/ejbca-ce).